# Starting another activity without extending Activity superclass

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a View class with some clickable bitmaps,in the onTouch method,i want to trigger a new activity when i have touched the bitmaps

```
Intent newintent = new Intent();
            newintent.setClass(view.getContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(newintent);
```

Since the class does not extends Activity,how can i start an activity without extending Activity?
the current error is :

```
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type DrawView
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided that your `MainMenu.class` is an `Activity` and you call the `startActivity()` method from a `View` of some sort you need to add a `Context` from which your new `Activity` will be started.

In your case it would be:

```
view.getContext().startActivity(newintent);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response,it worked immediately Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a context to do that something like this should be okay.

Declare a context for your view at the head of your class.

```
Context myContext = view.getContext();
```

And then use it to start your activity.

```
Intent newintent = new Intent();
        newintent.setClass(myContext,MainMenu.class);
        myContext.startActivity(newintent);myContext.startActivity(newintent);
```

Comment: You are awesome u save my life, I used your code in a class which `extends PagerAdapter` and it is working fine. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

When you are initializing your View class. In the constructor you pass Context of your activity class e.g

```
View v = new View(context)
```

In you Own View class constructor. Make a reference of this context as class-level object.

```
public class MyView extend View{
   private Context mContext = null;

   MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
   }

}
```

and when need to start a activity.

```
mContext. startActivity(newintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deliver the activity which the view in the show to this view.
The constructor of the view could be rewritten as:

```
View(Contenxt , ..)
```

And will use

```
context.start(...)
```